# Trouble when trying to do a VLOOKUP like with two pandas dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, vlookup

I've read a lot of questions regarding this matter, but none of it solved my problem.

I have 2 dataframes, one containing a list of all students of graduation level in a country, each one (each row) with informations about the student itself, as well as the course code.

On another dataframe, i have a list of unique course codes containing the address of the university that is assigned to the course code.

```
df1
CodCourse|Student|Address
1         10      outdated address
2         11      outdated address
2         12      outdated address
3         13      outdated address
3         14      outdated address
4         15      outdated address
4         16      outdated address

df2:
CodCourse   Address
1           Xth avenue
2           Yth avenue
3           Zth avenue
4           Nth avenue

Expected result:
df1
CodCourse|Student|Address
1         10      Xth avenue
2         11      Yth Street
2         12      Yth Street
3         13      Zth Street
3         14      Zth Street
4         15      Nth Street
4         16      Nth Street
```

I want to update the dataframe 1 address column with the address column of the dataframe 2.

I'm doing like this, but it's not working. I've tried with join and using a dictionary, but all I have is a failure.

```
df1=df1.merge(df2[['CodCourse','Address']], on='CodCourse', how='left')
```

Please, can anyone help me?

Thanks!
Eduardo.

Comment: what is not working? drop the initial `Address` in `df1` and this should work as expected. OR do you already have valuable data in `Address`?

Comment: I already have valuable data in Address in df1. I'd like to update it, because the initial data on df1 is outdated, so I'm doing this merge with df2. I don't want to add a column, just replace the values on df1 based on df2 (key is 'CodCourse'). Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the values in `df1`'s address you can use two methods.

in place modification:

```
df1.update(df1['CodCourse']
           .map(df2.set_index('CodCourse')['Address'])
           .rename('Address'))
```

assignment:

```
df1['Address'] = (df1['CodCourse']
                  .map(df2.set_index('CodCourse')['Address'])
                  .fillna(df1['Address'])
                 )
```

In both case this will replace any Address that has a new value in df2 while keeping old addresses that don't have a new value.

output:

```
   CodCourse  Student     Address
0          1       10  Xth avenue
1          2       11  Yth avenue
2          2       12  Yth avenue
3          3       13  Zth avenue
4          3       14  Zth avenue
5          4       15  Nth avenue
6          4       16  Nth avenue
```